How to make bootstrap datepicker be always visible/open?
Explaination
I am successfully using an 'input type=date' as a datepicker in bootstrap 5.3, to select the date for data viewing.
The problem that i have is: i have to click on it to be visible.
For my situation, it has to be always visible, like a javascript calendar.
Question
How can this be achieved?
The code
  <form id="Create" method="post" asp-page-handler="CreateDate" >
  <input class="btn btn-secondary " type="date" name='newdate' onchange='this.form.submit()' >


You are using Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5 at the same time? If not, correct your question tags and in any case, provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Bootstrap 5 doesn't have a datepicker. That's a regular HTML input.

As the built-in HTML <input type="date"> doesn't support always being visible. You can integrate the Bootstrap Datepicker and make it always visible.


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker-container').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        $('#newdate').val(e.format('yyyy-mm-dd')).change();
    });
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form id="Create" method="post" asp-page-handler="CreateDate">
        <div class="datepicker-container"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="newdate" id="newdate" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
    </form>
</div>




This doesn't looks Bootstrap styled. And the calendar disappears after clicking.

That library is over 10 years old, requires Bootstrap 2.0.4+ and jQuery 1.7.1+ why would you use that in any new project?

Use the below CDN links and the below function to call the date input


$('#datepkr').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap5'
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input id="datepkr" width="280" />




it has to be visible on page load, not after clicking on it.

ohh okay.. see another answer. onload visible also onclick visible.

Bootstrap 5.0.2? Why? Gijgo? Why?

use all cdn
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Datepicker JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

use this input date and this script
 <div class="container mt-5">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true
        });
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
    });
</script>


Bootstrap 4.5.2? Why?

This just makes the popout calendar visible initially and doesn't make the calendar always visible.
